# How to use #include with panel type window in extendscript?

Tags: extendscript

```
#targetengine main
#include "test.jsx"
var w = new Window("palette");
w.show();
```

..basically that, #include seems to stop panel window launching, what I am doing wrong/how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this work around:

```
#targetengine main

var ip = new File($.fileName);
var scriptPath = ip.path;

function incScript(sn) {
  eval('#includepath ' + scriptPath + '\n#include ' + sn); 
}

incScript('test.jsx');

var w = new Window("palette");
w.show();
```

Based on : https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/script-created-illustrator-palette-disappears-when-in-the-presence-of-include/m-p/9501010